# "Show current location" Button (Like Maps.app)

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, core-location

I state I'm a beginner so please **don't miss any step!**
I used that code to show and "jump" to the user location:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mv didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views {
for(MKAnnotationView *annotationView in views) {
    if(annotationView.annotation == mv.userLocation) {
        MKCoordinateRegion region;
        MKCoordinateSpan span;

        span.latitudeDelta=0.002;
        span.longitudeDelta=0.002; 

        CLLocationCoordinate2D location=mv.userLocation.coordinate;

        region.span=span;
        region.center=location;

        [mv setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
        [mv regionThatFits:region];
    }
}
```

But I'd like to request it just when I press a button.. How can I do it? (Remember: I'm a beginner!). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is not call your setRegion above, but just call it when you press the button.  Alternatively you can turn updating your map on and off with [locationManager startUpdatingLocation][locationManager stopUpdatingLocation], but leaving this on burns up battery, so be judicious.

Comment: I tried with this code but still does not work (It freezes when I press the button).

`-(IBAction)goToLocation {
    MKMapView *mapView;
    MKUserLocation *myLocation = [mapView userLocation];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = [[myLocation location] coordinate];
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coord, 350, 350);
    [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
    
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}`

Comment: Take out the calls to beginAnimations, setAnimationDuration and commitAnimations.  You've already told your setRegion call to animate, and it will do it better than what you're doing here. If it still has problems step through with the debugger, and see what line it freezes on.

Comment: And you'll probably want to add these lines back in there too:         region.span=span;
        region.center=location;